# xtype 'listview' issue with ExtJS plugin migration from 3.2.2 to Extjs 4.0.6

Tags: listview, extjs

I am using a extjs plugin that use xtype 'listview'. We have migrated to extjs 4.
Now the plugin stopped working because ListView is no longer available in extjs 4.
I tried replacing the xtype with 'grid' and 'gridpanel' in the plugin, it doesn't work.
Plugin Code :

```
//Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx = Ext.extend(Ext.form.Field,  {
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx', { 
extend : 'Ext.form.Field',
alias: 'widget.itemselectorex',
titleFrom: 'Available:',
titleTo: 'Selected:',
imagesDir: '.',       
useFilter: true,
filterWordStart: false,
filterIgnoreCase: true,
filterAnyMatch: true,
width: 300,
height: 200,
defaultAutoCreate: { tag: 'div' },
htmlEncode: true,
valueField: 'value',
displayField: 'text',
separator: ',',
itemSelector: 'dl',

initComponent: function()
{
    this.initToolbars();        
    this.initStores();      

    if (!this.rowTpl)
        this.rowTpl = '<div>{'+this.displayField+(this.htmlEncode ? ':htmlEncode' : '')+'}</div>';      

    this.cmp = new Ext.container.Container({
        layout: "vbox",
        cls: 'x-itemselectorex',
        layoutConfig: { align: 'stretch' },         
        items: [
            {
                height: 16,
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: "hbox",
                layoutConfig: { align: 'stretch' },
                items: [
                    {
                        flex: 0.5,
                        xtype: 'box',
                        cls: 'x-itemselectorex-title',
                        html: this.titleFrom
                    },{
                        width: 20,
                        xtype: 'box'
                    },{
                        flex: 0.5,
                        xtype: 'box',
                        cls: 'x-itemselectorex-title',
                        html: this.titleTo
                    }
                ]
            },{
                flex: 1,
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: "hbox",
                layoutConfig: { align: 'stretch' },
                items: [
                    {
                        flex: 0.5,
                        cls: 'x-itemselectorex-from',
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        border: false,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        tbar: this.tbarFrom,                            
                        items: {   
                            xtype: 'listview',
                            flex: 1,
                            ref: '../../lvFrom',
                            singleSelect: true,
                            emptyText: '<div class="x-itemselectorex-message">No available items</div>',
                            reserveScrollOffset: true,
                            hideHeaders: true,
                            columns: [{ width: 1, dataIndex: this.displayField, tpl: this.rowTpl }],
                            store: this.storeFrom,
                            listeners: {
                                scope: this,
                                dblclick: this.lvFromDblClickHandler
                            }
                        }                                 
                    },{
                        width: 20,
                        ref: 'tools',
                        cls: 'x-itemselectorex-tools',
                        xtype: 'box',
                        html: '<img src="'+this.imagesDir+'/right2.gif" class="x-itemselectorex-tool-icon x-itemselectorex-tool-add" qtip="Add"><br>'+
                              '<img src="'+this.imagesDir+'/left2.gif" class="x-itemselectorex-tool-icon x-itemselectorex-tool-remove" qtip="Remove"><br>'+
                              '<br>'+
                              '<img src="'+this.imagesDir+'/right3.gif" class="x-itemselectorex-tool-icon x-itemselectorex-tool-addall" qtip="Add all"><br>'+
                              '<img src="'+this.imagesDir+'/left3.gif" class="x-itemselectorex-tool-icon x-itemselectorex-tool-removeall" qtip="Remove all"><br>'
                    },{
                        flex: 0.5,
                        cls: 'x-itemselectorex-to',
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        border: false,
                        html: 'center',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        tbar: this.tbarTo,                          
                        items: {
                            xtype: 'listview',
                            flex: 1,
                            ref: '../../lvTo',
                            singleSelect: true,
                            emptyText: '<div class="x-itemselectorex-message">No selected items</div>',
                            reserveScrollOffset: true,
                            hideHeaders: true,
                            columns: [{ width: 1, dataIndex: this.displayField, tpl: this.rowTpl }],
                            store: this.storeTo,
                            listeners: {
                                scope: this,
                                dblclick: this.lvToDblClickHandler
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    this.storeReady = false;

    this.addEvents("change");

    Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    if (this.storeFrom.autoCreated) 
        this.onStoreLoad();
    else
        this.cmp.lvFrom.store.on('load', this.onStoreLoad, this);
},

onStoreLoad: function()
{
    this.storeReady = true;
    this.onValueSetReady();
}

,

initToolbars: function()
{
    this.tbarFrom = null;
    this.tbarTo = null;        
    if (this.useFilter)
    {
        this.tbarFrom = new Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.Filter({
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                filter: this.applyFilter,
                navigate: this.filterNavigate,
                clear: this.clearFilter
            }
        });

        this.tbarTo = new Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.Filter({
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                filter: this.applyFilter,
                navigate: this.filterNavigate,
                clear: this.clearFilter
            }
        });
    }
},

initStores: function()
{
    if (this.store)
    {
        this.storeFrom = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(this.store);
        if (this.storeFrom.autoCreated)
        {
            this.displayField = this.valueField = 'field1';
            if(!this.store.expandData){
                this.displayField = 'field2';
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.storeFrom = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            idIndex: 0,
            data: [],
            fields: [this.valueField, this.displayField],
            autoDestroy: true
        });
    }
    this.storeTo = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        idIndex: 0,
        data: [],
        fields: [this.valueField, this.displayField],
        autoDestroy: true
    });
    this.storeFrom.sort(this.displayField, 'ASC');
    this.storeTo.sort(this.displayField, 'ASC');
},

onValueSetReady: function()
{        
    if (this.value && this.storeReady && this.cmp.rendered)
    {            
        //console.log('onValueSetReady: '+this.value);
        this.setValue(this.value);
    }
},

onRender: function()
{
    Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);          

    var hiddenTag = {tag: "input", type: "hidden", value: this.value || "", name: this.name || Ext.id()};
    this.hiddenField = this.el.createChild(hiddenTag);

    this.cmp.on('render', this.onValueSetReady, this);

    this.on('render', function(){
        this.cmp.setWidth(this.getWidth());
        this.cmp.setHeight(this.getHeight());
        this.cmp.render(this.el);

        this.el.on("click", this.toolsClickHandler, this);
        this.on("resize", function(){
            this.cmp.setWidth(this.getWidth());
            this.cmp.setHeight(this.getHeight());
        }, this);     

        this.initDD();
    }, this);
},  

initDD: function()
{
    this.ddGroup = 'dd-group-'+Ext.id();            
    this.initDragZone(this.cmp);
    this.initDropZone(this.cmp);
},

initDragZone: function(v, ddGroup)
{
    var self = this;
    v.dragZone = new Ext.dd.DragZone(v.getEl(), {
        ddGroup: this.ddGroup,
        getDragData: function(e) 
        {
            var sourceEl = e.getTarget(self.itemSelector);
            if (sourceEl) 
            {
                var sourceCtrl = Ext.getCmp(e.getTarget(".x-list-wrap").id);                        
                var index = sourceCtrl.indexOf(sourceCtrl.findItemFromChild(sourceEl))

                d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                d.id = Ext.id();

                return v.dragData = {
                    sourceEl: sourceEl,
                    repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
                    ddel: d,
                    sourceCtrl: sourceCtrl, 
                    index: index
                }
            }
        },
        getRepairXY: function() {
            return this.dragData.repairXY;
        }
    });
},

initDropZone: function(v, ddGroup) 
{
    var self = this;
    v.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(v.getEl(), {
        ddGroup: this.ddGroup,
        getTargetFromEvent: function(e) {
            return e.getTarget('.x-list-wrap');
        },
        onNodeEnter : function(target, dd, e, data){ 
            Ext.fly(target).addClass('x-itemselectorex-target-hover');
        },
        onNodeOut : function(target, dd, e, data){ 
            Ext.fly(target).removeClass('x-itemselectorex-target-hover');
        },
        onNodeOver : function(target, dd, e, data){
            var targetCtrl = Ext.getCmp(target.id);
            if (targetCtrl == data.sourceCtrl) return false;
            return Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropAllowed;
        },
        onNodeDrop : function(target, dd, e, data){
            var targetCtrl = Ext.getCmp(target.id);
            if (targetCtrl != data.sourceCtrl)
            {
                var direction = data.sourceCtrl == v.lvFrom;
                self.moveItem(direction, data.index);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
},

doLayout: function()
{
    this.fireEvent('resize');
},

lvScrollTo: function(lv, el)
{
    var container = lv.getEl().select('.x-list-body').item(0);
    if (Ext.isObject(el)) el = lv.getNode(el);
    if (el) Ext.fly(el).scrollIntoView(container, false);
},

filterFunc: function(rec, filter)
{
    var value = rec.get(this.displayField);

    if (this.filterIgnoreCase) value = value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    if (this.filterIgnoreCase) filter = filter.toLocaleUpperCase();

    if (Ext.isEmpty(filter)) return true;

    if (this.filterAnyMatch && this.filterWordStart)
    {
        var re_opts = this.filterIgnoreCase ? 'i' : '';
        var re = new RegExp('(^|[\\s\\.!?;"\'\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}])'+Ext.escapeRe(filter), re_opts);
        return re.test(value);
    }
    else if (this.filterAnyMatch)
    {
        var re_opts = this.filterIgnoreCase ? 'i' : '';
        var re = new RegExp(Ext.escapeRe(filter), re_opts);
        return re.test(value);
    }
    else
    {
        var re_opts = this.filterIgnoreCase ? 'i' : '';
        var re = new RegExp('^\s*'+Ext.escapeRe(filter), re_opts);
        return re.test(value);
    }
},

applyFilter: function(tbar, filter)
{
    var store = tbar == this.tbarFrom ? this.cmp.lvFrom.store : this.cmp.lvTo.store;
    store.clearFilter();
    if (String(filter).trim() != "")
    {
        store.filterBy(function(rec, id){
            return this.filterFunc(rec, filter);    
        }, this);
    }
},

clearFilter: function(tbar)
{
    var store = tbar == this.tbarFrom ? this.cmp.lvFrom.store : this.cmp.lvTo.store;
    store.clearFilter();
    tbar.focus(100);
},

filterNavigate: function(tbar, key)
{
    var lv = tbar == this.tbarFrom ? this.cmp.lvFrom : this.cmp.lvTo;
    var indexes = lv.getSelectedIndexes();      
    var navkeys = [Ext.EventObject.DOWN, Ext.EventObject.PAGE_DOWN, Ext.EventObject.UP, Ext.EventObject.PAGE_UP];
    if (key == Ext.EventObject.ENTER)
    {
        Ext.iterate(indexes, function(idx){
            this.moveItem(lv == this.cmp.lvFrom ? 1 : 0, idx);
        }, this);
    } 
    else if (navkeys.indexOf(key) != -1)
    {
        if (key == Ext.EventObject.DOWN)
        {
            var index = indexes.length == 0 ? null : indexes[0];
            var new_index = (lv.store.getCount() - 1 == index || index == null) ? 0 : index + 1;
        }
        else if (key == Ext.EventObject.PAGE_DOWN)
        {
            var new_index = lv.store.getCount() > 0 ? lv.store.getCount() - 1 : null;                   
        }
        else if (key == Ext.EventObject.UP)
        {
            var index = indexes.length == 0 ? null : indexes[0];
            var new_index = (index == 0 || index == null) ? lv.store.getCount() - 1 : index - 1;
        }
        else if (key == Ext.EventObject.PAGE_UP)
        {
            var new_index = lv.store.getCount() > 0 ? 0 : null;
        }
        lv.select(new_index);
        this.lvScrollTo(lv, lv.store.getAt(new_index));            
    }
    tbar.focus();
},

toolsClickHandler: function(e)
{
    if (this.disabled) return;
    var el = e.getTarget('.x-itemselectorex-tool-icon', 2, 1);
    if (!el) return;
    if (el.hasClass('x-itemselectorex-tool-add'))
    {
        var indexes = this.cmp.lvFrom.getSelectedIndexes();
        Ext.iterate(indexes, function(index){
            this.moveItem(1, index);
        }, this);
    }
    else if (el.hasClass('x-itemselectorex-tool-remove'))
    {
        var indexes = this.cmp.lvTo.getSelectedIndexes();
        Ext.iterate(indexes, function(index){
            this.moveItem(0, index);
        }, this);
    }
    else if (el.hasClass('x-itemselectorex-tool-addall'))
    {
        var recs = this.cmp.lvFrom.store.getRange();
        Ext.iterate(recs, function(rec){
            this.moveItem(1, this.cmp.lvFrom.store.indexOf(rec));
        }, this);
    }
    else if (el.hasClass('x-itemselectorex-tool-removeall'))
    {
        this.setValue('');
    }
},

lvFromDblClickHandler: function(lv, index, node, e)
{
    this.moveItem(1, index);
},

lvToDblClickHandler: function(lv, index, node, e)
{
    this.moveItem(0, index);
},

moveItem: function(direction, index)
{
    var lvSrc = direction ? this.cmp.lvFrom : this.cmp.lvTo;
    var lvDest = direction ? this.cmp.lvTo : this.cmp.lvFrom;            
    var rec = lvSrc.store.getAt(index);
    if (!rec) return;   
    lvDest.store.addSorted(rec);
    lvSrc.store.removeAt(index);
    this.applyValue();         
},

applyValue: function()
{
    var data = this.cmp.lvTo.store.collect(this.valueField, false, true);   // not null, without filter
    var value = data.join(this.separator);
    this.hiddenField.dom.value = value;
    this.fireEvent("change", this, value);
},

getValue: function()
{
    if (!this.rendered) return this.value;
    return this.hiddenField.dom.value;
},

setValue: function(value) 
{   
    //console.log('setValue: '+value);
    if (this.cmp.rendered)
    {
        var ids = [];
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(value)) ids = value.split(',');
        this.cmp.lvTo.store.each(function(rec){
            this.moveItem(0, this.cmp.lvTo.store.indexOf(rec));
        }, this);               
        Ext.iterate(ids, function(id) {                    
            var find_re = new RegExp("^"+Ext.escapeRe(id)+"$", "i");
            var idx = this.cmp.lvFrom.store.find(this.valueField, find_re);
            if (idx != -1) this.moveItem(1, idx);
        }, this);
        this.hiddenField.dom.value = value;
    }
    this.value = value; 
},

initValue: function()
{
    // no needed, value initialize via store<=>grid listeners
    // keep method here to override parent's method
},

loadData: function(data)
{
    this.store.loadData(data);
}
});

//Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.Filter = Ext.extend(Ext.Toolbar,  {
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.Filter', {
extend : 'Ext.Toolbar',
initComponent: function()
{
    this.items = [
        'Filter:',
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',             
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                keyup: function(obj, e)
                {                       
                    if (obj.getValue() != obj.prev_value)
                        this.fireEvent('filter', this, obj.getValue());
                    obj.prev_value = obj.getValue();
                },
                keydown: function(obj, e)
                {
                    if (Ext.isWebKit || Ext.isIE) 
                        this.fireEvent('navigate', this, e.getKey(), e);
                },
                keypress: function(obj, e)
                {
                    this.fireEvent('navigate', this, e.getKey(), e);
                }
            }
        },{
            text: 'Clear',
            scope: this,
            handler: function()
            {
                this.clearValue();
                this.fireEvent('clear', this);
            }
        }
    ];
    this.addEvents('navigate', 'filter', 'clear');
    Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.Filter.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    this.on('resize', this.onResize);
},

onResize: function()
{
    var inputWidth = this.getWidth() - (this.get(0).getWidth() + this.get(2).getWidth() + 5);
    this.get(1).setWidth(inputWidth);
},

clearValue: function()
{
    this.get(1).setValue('');
},

focus: function(delay)
{
    this.get(1).focus(delay);
}
});
```

My Code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ext-4.0.6/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css">      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-4.0.6/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
    Ext.onReady(function(){    
        Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.prototype.imagesDir = './images';

        var data = [
            [1, 'value1'],
            [2, 'value2'],
            [3, 'value3'],
            [4, 'value4'],
            [5, 'value5'],
            [6, 'value6'],
            [7, 'value7'],
            [8, 'value8'],
            [9, 'value9'],
            [10, 'value10'],
            [11, 'value11'],
            [12, 'value12']
        ];


        var win = new Ext.Window({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Window',
            width: 500,
            autoHeight: true,
            items: {            
                xtype: 'form',
                border: false,
                padding: 10,
                items: [
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'Item Selector<br>(local)',
                        xtype: "itemselectorex",
                        anchor: '100%',
                        store: data,
                        value: '1,3,5',
                        name: 'itemselector1'
                    }               
                ],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'OK',
                        handler: function()
                        {
                            alert('value: '+Ext.encode(this.ownerCt.ownerCt.form.getValues()));
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
        win.show();

    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

CSS (Ext.ux.form.ItemSelectorEx.css):

```
    .x-itemselectorex { -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; }
    .x-itemselectorex-message { font: 12px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; text-align: center; margin: 5px }
    .x-itemselectorex-title { font: bold 11px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #777; padding-left: 3px }
    .x-itemselectorex-from { border: 1px solid #ccc }
    .x-itemselectorex-to { border: 1px solid #ccc }
    .x-itemselectorex-tools { text-align: center; padding-top: 5px }
    .x-itemselectorex-tool-icon { margin-bottom: 5px }    
    .x-itemselectorex-row { font: 11px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; padding: 1px; }
    .x-itemselectorex .x-itemselectorex-target-hover { background-color: #F7FFF4; }
```

Comment: Please post the plugin code and the code that calls it.

Comment: @JuanMendes You can find the complete example at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124549-3.x-Ext.ux.ItemSelectorEx. I made one basic change to the plugin to incorporate ExtJS 4 style.I replaced 'Ext.extend' with 'Ext.define' and commented out "Ext.reg". I can still send you my code but I am not sure how to do it here.

Comment: We need code, just paste it in the question, and make sure it's well formatted

Comment: @JuanMendes I have added the code. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: ref: "../../../" No longer works in ExtJS 4, I think that is your first problem. The easy way it to create a reference yourself of letting ref do it+

Comment: @JuanMendes Correct. I tried to change "ref" but I am not sure about how to do it. Also I am not sure if I will be able to change xtype "listview" with "grid" or "gridpanel". I tried using Ext.ComponentQuery.query() by assigning "id" to the panel but I am having hard time using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that ref: "../../../" No longer works in ExtJS 4. Also, what you have is not a plugin, it's a Component, it extends Component, not a plugin.

The simplest alternative is to give your object an itemId and then query for it from the container after it has laid out its children.

```
// This is all inside your initComponent
items: {
    xtype: 'listview',
    flex: 1,
    // This is how you can find it after the component renders and is 
    // much better than just using an id
    itemId: 'lvFrom',
    singleSelect: true,
    emptyText: '<div class="x-itemselectorex-message">No available items</div>',
    reserveScrollOffset: true,
    hideHeaders: true,
    columns: [{ width: 1, dataIndex: this.displayField, tpl: this.rowTpl }],
    store: this.storeFrom,
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        dblclick: this.lvFromDblClickHandler
    }
}

// Now you have to set an event handler
this.on('afterlayout', function(){
    this.cmp.lvFrom = this.cmp.down('#lvFrom');
}, this, {single: true});
```

You'll still have to deal with the differences from the list to the table view. Take a look at [the upgrade guide](https://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/)?

Comment: Thank you again for response. There is a problem with creating references. I might be making silly mistake but I am new to ExtJS 4. First xtype 'listview' is not valid in ExtJS 4. With your last statement did you intend to tell that I need change the xtype to 'tableview'?. I tried using the following syntax:                                          Ext.widget('gridpanel',{ flex: 1, ...}) and was able to create the widget but the reference here is this.lvFrom and the code uses this.cmp.lvFrom. we need to link it to the Container obj 'cmp', because the code uses references like 'this.cmp.lvFrom'

Comment: I've updated the answer with another approach that could work, but to get help on a problem like this, you have to be able to isolate the problem better, explain the error messages, shrink your code to a  single problem at a time, I can't dedicate that much time and the upgrade from 3 to 4 can be painful, especially if you're not as experienced with Ext-JS

Comment: Thank you Juan Mendes. The hint is useful and I will try to incorporate these changes.